# Unable to execute functions through keyboard events

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a HTML game in which i have to call jump and walk function in order to make the character jump and walk respectively using keyboard keys. But i am unable to do so!!
Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById('myCanvas').onkeypress = function()  { 
        decision();
}
function decision(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 87) {
         jump();    
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 68) {
         walk();
        }
    }
```

i.e with 'w' key it has to jump and with 'd' key it has walk.!!

Comment: I think you should pass e to decision, somthing like `document.getElementById('myCanvas').onkeypress = function(e)  { 
        decision(e);
}`

Comment: document.getElementById('myCanvas').onkeypress=decision;

Answer (score 2):

```
function decision(e){
   var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode;

   if (keyCode === 87) {
      jump();    
   }
   if(keyCode === 68) {
      walk();
   }
}

document.getElementById('myCanvas').onkeypress = decision;
```

You weren't passing the e argument to the callback, so I'm surprised it didn't blow up as undefined.

Note also how I assign the `decision` function reference directly to the `onkeypress` property, instead of wrapping it in an anonymous function. This will pass the arguments straight through as desired, with the expected `Window` context (though depending on your particular `this` requirements inside the callback this approach may not always be suitable).

Additionally, please make sure you only query for an element by id once you can be sure its available (ie. place this code somewhere after the target node appears in the DOM, or use a framework like jQuery)

Lastly, `e.keyCode` may not be defined as you expect in all browsers so you may want to guard against this as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById('myCanvas').onkeypress = function(e)  { 
    decision(e);
}

function decision(e){
    if (e.which == 87) {
     jump();    
    }
    if(e.which == 68) {
     walk();
    }
}
```

---

Also bear in mind that you can use `e.which` or `e.keyCode` or `e.charCode`. Just check for all them, it depends on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing in the event e to the `decision()` function

```
document.getElementById('myCanvas').onkeypress = function(e) { 
    decision(e);
}

function decision(e){

    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (key == 87) {
        jump(); 
    }
    if(key == 68) {
        walk();
    }
}
```